# Using Compare Validator to compare two dropdownlists in grid item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have two dropdown lists in my grid if one is selected and the other is not selected on the client side it should populate  error message asking user to select a value from the second dropdown. i would like to use compare validator for this function any help is deeply appreciated

```
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrate1" runat="server" Width="300px">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrate2" runat="server" Width="300px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" Operator = "LessThan" ErrorMessage="Rate1 should be less than Rate2" ControlToValidate = "ddlrate1" ControlToCompare = "ddlrate2"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

This is what am trying with please give me suggestions

Comment: you can use RequiredFieldValidator

Answer (score 0):

you can use RequiredFieldValidator

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="Cause" InitialValue="0" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="Please Selecte One " Display="Dynamic">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Cause" runat="server" CssClass="drbox">
<asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">- select one -</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">cause1</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Thanks For Answering Mahmoude but what am trying is if one is selected and the other is not selected then it should give a message asking to select the second dropdown

Comment: you mean if there's no one selected its okay. but if one selected user must select the other one

Comment: Yes Absolutely that's what am trying

Comment: you have two way searching about "CustomValidator" or you can do it from code behind by using if statement 
and to stop any drbox validation you can use this "ValidatorID.Enabled = false;"

Comment: if you stuck let me know

Comment: i dont want to achieve this by server side validation and i have no knowledge about custom validator so am stuck please help!